# Is it possible to specify user-scalable="yes" only to images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, mobile-safari

I'm developing course lectures for mobile devices, and have zoom capabilities disabled. I would like to keep it this way for everything on the page except images.

I've come close to what I'm aiming to do before by having the meta user-scalable="no" replaced with "yes" via jquery when the user clicks on a link that opens a pop up window within the page, allowing the user to then zoom in when the pop up window was open, and many of these pop up windows contained the images I wanted to enable the zoom for.

However, not all of the images I want the user to be able to zoom in on are inside of the pop up window, and I don't dictate what content goes where. I only control the gui (css, script files, etc.)

Is there a way to apply scalable="yes" to images only, while keeping the rest of the gui scalable="no"?

Comment: How would you zoom in on only an image and not the rest of the page?  I don't think that works.

Comment: It would probably be a little strange for the UX, but innitially I was thinking a div around images with overflow: none; causing them to be able to zoom on the image without the rest of the content being distorted.

Comment: Just wondering if you found a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Scaling part of the page (the image) and not the rest of it doesn't really make sense. I think you'll probably be happy with the default behavior of images in the browser. Set `user-scalable="no"` for the website as normal, for images have links that open them in a new window (`target="_blank"`) this will open a new browser tab and allow the user to zoom until they decide to go back to the page.

This method is usually far superior for mobile compared to something like lightbox due to performance benefits of the browser only needing to display the image.

I'll also add that many users get annoyed when user scaling is disabled (myself included). You may want to consider setting a minimum scale and allowing the user to zoom if they want instead.

Comment: I'll get annoyed too when user scaling is disabled on many sites, or there's a specific mobile version without certain features. This project however, is a little different from most websites, forums etc. It's a course. It's basically a gui for browser based, 30-70 page books which consist of 95% text, and some images here and there to break the monotony, and onc in a while an image is kind of important.

Comment: The `user-scalable='no'` on Chrome mostly works on Android, not on Apple. I am also searching for a solution to this problem on a modal. I want users not to be able to zoom (still IOS users can :|) on a page but to be able to zoom when modal is shown.
I would recommend to check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action